# Como puedo importar un dump file (base de datos) de mysql a sql server 2014?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo algunos dump files de mysql y necesito importarlos a Sql server 2014, alguien sabe como puedo lograrlo?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá con un DUMP sea algo más complejo.

Yo te diría que recargues el dump directamente en un nuevo gestor Mysql (si ya no dispones de la BD original) y después pruebes con [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2017/02/21/released-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-v7-3/)

Permite importar bases de datos como MySQL u Oracle.

En particular, [la versión de Mysql está aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54257)

Comment: Gracias, lo he intentado pero al parecer la base de datos es demasiado grande y me causa muchos confilctos.

Comment: Por? Que le pasa?? Que te dice? Recuperas Demasiados registros ?

Comment: Pues intente con un gestor sql (heidiSQL) pero al parecer la base de datos es demasiado grande, una de ellas es de sobre 40 Gb  y hace que le prorama deje de funcionar. Que gestor me recomendarias usar?

Comment: no puedes usar un mysql normal???  Se supone que te permite TB de información

Comment: Quizá sea un tema de limitaciones de tu sistema??Xq heidiSql ??  Mysql debería dejarte. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente deben ser limitaciones del sistema. Despues de investigar un poco veo que muchos coindicen con las alternativas que tu me diste. Saludos